# Oauth.io domain not authorized even though I've whitelisted it on oauth.io

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, oauth.io

Edit: this is my first post, sorry if I make any noob mistakes!

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Origin "http://cntxt.github.io/" does not match any registered domain/url on oauth.io
    at Object.sendCallback (...oauth.js:669:15)
    at getMessage (...oauth.js:172:36)
```

But on my **oauth.io** app, I've whitelisted the following:

[image]
I whitelisted them all about 12 hours ago, but I suppose it could take more time than that. 
This seems like it should be fairly straightforward, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: did you ever solve this? having the same issue on a github.io domain

Comment: Did you whitelisted localhost domain on auth.io. if not, then try whitelisting your localhost domain. Another option would be to enable this API key for public use (for 5 min) for your testing.